# Disable add to cart button for some products IDs in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

In WooCommerce, I'm trying to disable add to cart button for an array of product IDs but I can't find the problem.

I am trying to use this function:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'my_woocommerce_is_purchasable', 10, 2);

function my_woocommerce_is_purchasable($is_purchasable, $product) {
    $id=check(); // This function return an array of IDs
    foreach ($id as $id_p){
        return ($product->id = $id_p ? false : $is_purchasable);
    }
}
```

And this is my `check()` function code *(update)*:

```
function check() { 
    $listproduit = get_woocommerce_product_list();
    $score = get_score_user(); 
    foreach ($listproduit as $products) { 
        if ($products[1] >= 5000) { 
            $listid = $products[0]; 
            return $listid; 
            // print_r($listid); 
        } 
    } 
    return $listid; 
}
```

But this doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: the `foreach ...` with an inline `return` doesn't make sense IMHO. It will compare the first entry returned from `check()`function and will return false if $id_p is not false, otherwise the value of $is_purchasable will be returned. Is that what you intend to do?

Comment: i want to apply the woocommerce_is_purchasable with the value of $is_purchasable=false to an array of products id which are returned by the check function thank you for help  ----> i want to block the bottom add to cart for those products id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated for WooCommerce 3+ *(still works in WooCommerce 8.1+)*

Use `in_array()` instead like:

```php
// Here your settings: The array of non-purchasable product IDs
function non_purchasable_product_ids() {
     return array( 37, 53, 128, 129 );
}

// The active function: removing/disabling add to cart for the defined products
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_purchasable', 'filter_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'filter_is_purchasable', 10, 2);
function filter_is_purchasable($is_purchasable, $product ) {
    if( in_array( $product->get_id(), non_purchasable_product_ids() ) ) {
         return false;
    } 
    return $is_purchasable;
}
```

where `non_purchasable_product_ids()` is the function that returns an array of non-purchasable products IDs *(simplified)*.

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this but eventually found the answer. Hope it helps:

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'wp66176371_remove_product_description_add_cart_button', 1 );
function wp66176371_remove_product_description_add_cart_button() {
global $product;
if(in_array($product->get_id(), array(414, 427))){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 
'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
}
}
```