# Remove add-to-cart for one specific product Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, product, cart

I would like to hide/remove add-to-cart button only for one, specific product everywhere it is displayed.
This solution doesn't work in my website: [Disable add to cart button for some products IDs in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39701443/disable-add-to-cart-button-for-some-products-ids-in-woocommerce)

Could anyone help me how the code should look like only for one product?